Bergman point evaluation inequality
For an analytic function $f$ on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $\|f\|_p = \int_\mathbb{D} |f(z)|^p \,dA(z) < \infty$ we have the following inequality,
$$
|f(z)| \leq (1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}} \|f\|_p, \quad z \in \mathbb{D}.
$$
Let's say that now $\|f'\|_p < \infty$ and that $f(0)=0$, my intuition says that it must be true that,
$$
|f(z)| \leq (1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1} \|f'\|_p, \quad z \in \mathbb{D}.
$$
Because,
$$
|f(z)| = |\int_0^z f'(\omega) d\omega| \leq \int_0^z |f'(\omega)| \, d\omega \leq \|f'\|_p \int_0^z (1-|\omega|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  d\omega.
$$
And I guess,
$$
\int_0^z (1-|\omega|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}} d\omega \leq (1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1},
$$
as we are integrating. Any suggestion or help into how to compute that estimate?

An obvious problem with your inequality is the possibility to add arbitrary constants to $f$ without changing $f'$. I suppose you implicitly use an assumption $f(0) = 0$, in particular, to force the equality $f(z) = \int_0^z f'(w)dw$. Do you wish to add this assumption to your question?

@Matsmir okay, now I have added the asssumption. Thanks!

for $p<2$ the result holds with a constant $|f(z)| \leq C_p(1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1} |f'|_p, \quad z \in \mathbb{D}$ but for $p>2$ it cannot hold since that would give $f(z) \to 0, |z| \to 1$ and that is not possible for nonzero analytic $f$

@Conrad okay I see that for $p>2$ by the maximum modulus principle it's not possible. For $p=2$, the integral can be solved and we get a logarithmic growth. But for $p<2$ I don't see how to proceed.

Here is a solution for $p<2$ (as noted in the comments $p>2$ cannot work since by a theorem of Privalov no nonzero analytic function in the unit disc regardless of any conditions on it can have $f(z) \to 0, |z| \to 1$, while $p=2$ is a simple explicit computation as noted in the comments also).
With the parametrization $\omega=re^{i\arg z}, 0 \le r \le |z|$ so $dw=e^{i\arg z}dr, |dw|=dr$ we have
$$|\int_0^z (1-|\omega|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  d\omega| \le \int_0^z (1-|\omega|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  |d\omega|=\int_0^{|z|} (1-r^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  dr$$
Clearly for $|z| \le 1/2$ one has $$\frac{\int_0^{|z|} (1-r^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  dr}{(1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1}} \le C_{1p}$$ since the LHS above is a continuous nonnegative function on the closed disc $0 \le |z| \le 1/2$ so has a maximum depending only on $p$
If $|z|>1/2$ we can write:
$$\int_0^r (1-r^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  dr=C_{2p}+\int_{1/2}^{|z|}(1-r^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  dr$$ where $$C_{2p}=\int_0^{1/2} (1-r^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  dr \le C_{1p}(1-|1/2|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1}\le C_{1p}(1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1}$$ since $-2/p+1<0$ and $|z|>1/2$
Also $$\int_{1/2}^{|z|}(1-r^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  dr \le \frac{1}{2}\int_{1/2}^{|z|}r(1-r^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  dr= $$$$=\frac{1}{4(2/p-1)}((1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1}-(1-|1/2|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1}) \le C_{3p}(1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1}$$
So with $C_p=C_{1p}+C_{3p}, C_{3p}=\frac{1}{4(2/p-1)}$ and $C_{1p}$ an exercise in basic calculus if one wants it explicit, we get:
$$\int_0^{|z|} (1-r^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}}  dr \le C_p(1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1}$$ for all $|z|<1$ and the required result follows: $$|f(z)| \leq C_p(1-|z|^2)^{-\frac{2}{p}+1} \|f'\|_p, \quad z \in \mathbb{D}$$
